# Check simple proof that $\lim\limits_{s\to0^+}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nf(n)^{-s}=-\frac12$ if $f>0$, $f''\le0$ and $f(+\infty)=+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> $f:[1,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}_+$ satisfies  $\ f''\leq0,\ f(+\infty)=+\infty $. Prove 
>   $$\lim_{s\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n[f(n)]^{-s}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Some of my friends showed me this question and declared it's difficult. However I've found a quite simple proof. Could you help me examine if it's correct?

Proof: Obviously, $\ f$ is strictly increasing. For $s\in(0,1)$, due to Leibniz's Test, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n[f(n)]^{-s}$ converges and we denote it by $(-1)S(s)$.
 $$f''\leq0\ \&\ x^{-s}\ \text{is convex}\Rightarrow\ x^{-s}\circ f=[f]^{-s}\ \text{is convex}$$
$$\Rightarrow\ f^{-s}(n)-f^{-s}(n+1)\geq f^{-s}(n+1)-f^{-s}(n+2),\quad n\in\mathbb{N}_+$$

Let $a_n^s$ represents $f^{-s}(n)$, now we have,

$$S(s)=a_1^s-a_2^s+a_3^s-a_4^s\cdots\ .$$
Define $S\tilde(s)$ as
$$S\tilde(s)=a_2^s-a_3^s+a_4^s-a_5^s\cdots\ .$$

Notice that 
$$S(s)\geq S\tilde(s),\ S(s)\leq S\tilde(s)+a_1^s-a_2^s, \ S(s)+S\tilde(s)=a_1^s,$$
which implies
$$a_1^s/2\leq S(s)\leq a_1^s-a_2^s/2\ .$$

Let $s\to 0^+$, now we proved $\lim_{s\to 0^+}S(s)=1/2$, that is the conclusion.

Comment: $$ S(s)+S\tilde(s)=a_{1}^{s}\color{red}{-\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}^{s}} $$

Comment: @HazemOrabi I think that limit is 0, since $f(+\infty)=+\infty$.

Comment: Not so clear: $$ \lim_{\begin{align} n&\to\infty \\ s&\to0^{+}\end{align}}\left[f(n+1)\right]^{-s} \,\longrightarrow\, 0^0 $$

Comment: @HazemOrabi No it's not like that. You must take the limit with n and s separately. You can't simultaneously take both. First we let n goes to infty, so the term converges to 0, when s is still some positive constant number. Then the rest becomes $\lim_{s\to 0^+} 0=0$.

Comment: What I meant to say is: $$  \lim_{s\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\left(f(n)\right)^{-s} = \lim_{s\to0^+}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\left(f(2n)\right)^{-s}-\left(f(2n-1)\right)^{-s}\right]$$ 
Hence, the start of your proof is okay. But splitting the odd and even terms will take it to a muddy water. Apologizing and good luck.

Comment: @XIAODAQU Why is the $f$ strictly increasing?

Comment: @LiTaichi If not, then $f'=0$  for some point, and must  $\leq 0$ behind that, which is contrary to $f(+\infty)=+\infty$.